# SQL Server : Union two tables with different columns

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to union two tables with different columns:

```
Table 1:                                 Table 2:

Name  Region  Price_2018 Cost_2018       Name Region Price_2017 Cost_2017
-----------------------------------      ---------------------------------
A     US      12         32              A    US     30         56
B     CH      20         15              D    JP     45         20
C     EU      30         16              B    CH     60         30
```

The result table will be

```
 Name  Region  Price_2018 Cost_2018 Price_2017 Cost_2017
 -------------------------------------------------------
 A     US      12         32        30         56
 B     CH      20         15        60         30
 C     EU      30         16        null       null
 D     JP      null       null      45         20
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's **not** a `UNION` , but rather a `JOIN`, between these two tables

Comment: You must use a `JOIN` for that, not `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But JOIN only gives me the common between two tables. I still want the unique values though.

Comment: You must use `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `full outer join` :

```
select coalesce(t1.name, t2.name), coalesce(t1.Region, t2.Region),
       t1.Price_2018, t1.Cost_2018, t2.Price_2017, t2.Cost_2017
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name = t1.name;
```